# replacing * with %*%

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub

I have an equation as shown below.

```
"2 * (exp(B * z) * z * ((exp(B * z)) - y))/(2 * m)"
```

I am trying to replace only those * where the * is between two alphabets and not between an alphabet and a number. The final output would look like this.

```
"2 * (exp(B %*% z) %*% z %*% ((exp(B %*% z)) - y))/(2 * m)"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @RichardScriven, this is string.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like this will work for your example

```
x <- "2 * (exp(B * z) * z * ((exp(B * z)) - y))/(2 * m)"
gsub("([^0-9]\\s)\\*(\\s[^0-9])","\\1%*%\\2", x, perl=T)
# "2 * (exp(B %*% z) %*% z * ((exp(B %*% z)) - y))/(2 * m)"
```

Comment: Now we need a question where you parse by class of object in the workspace and use `%*%` where one of the objects is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach based on lookbehind and lookahead:

```
s <- "2 * (exp(B * z) * z * ((exp(B * z)) - y))/(2 * m)"

gsub("(?<=\\D )\\*(?= \\D)","%*%", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "2 * (exp(B %*% z) %*% z %*% ((exp(B %*% z)) - y))/(2 * m)"
```